# Kong responds 404 when accessed vi Postman

Tags: api, curl, postman, kong

I have set up an API and Kong. I have successfully installed Kong. In fact, i can access my APIs via curl on cli. However, when I use Postman, which I use all of the time, I get the response

```
{
  "request_path": "/api/v1/",
  "message": "API not found with these values",
  "request_host": [
    "192.168.33.13"
  ]
}
```

Ps. Im new to kong so please bear with me.

---

```
$ kong start
[INFO] Kong 0.7.0
[INFO] Using configuration: /etc/kong/kong.yml
[INFO] Setting working directory to /usr/local/kong
[INFO] database...........cassandra keyspace=kong ssl=verify=false enabled=false replication_factor=1 contact_points=127.0.0.1:9042 replication_strategy=SimpleStrategy timeout=5000 data_centers=
[INFO] dnsmasq............address=127.0.0.1:8053 dnsmasq=true port=8053
[INFO] serf ..............-profile=wan -rpc-addr=127.0.0.1:7373 -event-handler=member-join,member-leave,member-failed,member-update,member-reap,user:kong=/usr/local/kong/serf_event.sh -bind=0.0.0.0:7946 -node=precise64_0.0.0.0:7946 -log-level=err
[INFO] Trying to auto-join Kong nodes, please wait..
[WARN] Cannot auto-join the cluster because no nodes were found
[WARN] ulimit is currently set to "1024". For better performance set it to at least "4096" using "ulimit -n"
[INFO] nginx .............admin_api_listen=0.0.0.0:8001 proxy_listen=0.0.0.0:8000 proxy_listen_ssl=0.0.0.0:8443
[OK] Started

$ curl -i -X POST --url http://localhost:8001/apis/ --data 'name=geospatial' --data 'upstream_url=http://192.168.33.10/' --data 'request_host=192.168.33.10'
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Fri, 08 Apr 2016 14:38:22 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Server: kong/0.7.0

{"upstream_url":"http:\/\/192.168.33.10\/","id":"240e6cc6-626f-4629-9551-0d341a57adba","name":"geospatial","created_at":1460126302000,"request_host":"192.168.33.10"}
```

When I curl the api...

```
$ curl -i -X GET -H "Host: 192.168.33.10" "http://192.168.33.13:8000/api/v1/"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 08 Apr 2016 14:56:04 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 70
Connection: keep-alive
Server: Werkzeug/0.11.4 Python/2.7.6
X-Kong-Upstream-Latency: 4
X-Kong-Proxy-Latency: 0
Via: kong/0.7.0

{"status": 200, "message": 200, "data": "Hello World!", "error": null}
```

How ever when I try to use Postman, I get a 404 status response.
with this body

```
{
  "request_path": "/api/v1/",
  "message": "API not found with these values",
  "request_host": [
    "192.168.33.13"
  ]
}
```

Am I missing something?

Disclaimer:
I am using Postman because I am lazy and because my clients will mostly be using Postman as well. So dont tell me to to use curl instead :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just encountered the same problem.
In order to send to Kong you need to add Host header, but Postman has some restricted headers that are blocked and Host is one of them.
You need to download Chrome Inspector to send the Host header.
For more details - 
https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests

Comment: Thanks!!!, this was a late but still the answer im looking for :) thanks for the link.. didnt know they had header restrictions...

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the header parameter named **"Host"** in order to Kong find your API.

You can see that your curl command have this parameter

```
-H "Host: 192.168.33.10"
```

Comment: Yes, I added that to the request as well, still the same.

Comment: You can check the "Generate Code" Option in Postman, and match it with your curl command. That way you'll find out if you set up everything correctly.

Comment: That's how i troubleshoot when I got a similar error.

Comment: I also already checked on that, and for the record, the curl I used in my question that succeeded was the generate code of postman.. HAHA! that's why I am posting this question because this is weird for me.